# PreparedStatement not working for substring_index?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using this:

```
PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE attributeId = ? AND substring_index(substring_index(rowIdCombo,',',2),',',-1) = ?");

preStatement.setString(1, anAttributeID.toString());
preStatement.setString(2, locationID.toString());
```

Searching using the same query works fine on the MySQL terminal. It's only when using `PreparedStatement` in `Java` that it doesn't.

rowIdCombo is basically a string of numbers with comma separated values. Something like this: `23,56,64,3`.

The result set returned is empty. How do I get this query to work?

Comment: Isn't it easier to Split the rowIdCombo in Java, and write a cleaner PreparedStatement? For readability issues at least and also easier to debug.

Comment: If I don't use `substring_index`, the select * will return 2 million rows, which will be a problem because I'm querying a database on a server. I need the substring to be found by SQL itself, so that only the few necessary rows would be returned. Also, because the SQL cursor does not last for long when a large number of rows are being returned.

Comment: Hold On, According to your code, rowIdCombo is being treated as the literal rowIdCombo String instead the actual value (23,56,64,2).

Comment: I don't think so. See the nested `substring_index`. The problem is either that the result of `substring_index` is not being equated to the ? or the format of the substring_index having brackets is somehow not being interpreted correctly by PreparedStatement.

Comment: My bad, at some point I thought rowIdCombo was part of the input and not a column in SomeTable...  So dumb, nvm then.

Comment: what will be the output of this `System.out.println(preStatement);` if you place it just after the 2 `setString()` ?

Comment: The output is `com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@223d2c72: SELECT * FROM mydb.SomeTable WHERE attributeId = '6' AND substring_index(substring_index(rowIdCombo,',',2),',',-1) = '1'`. When I run it on the SQL commandprompt, it results in an empty set. Although when I substitute the `= '1'` at the end with just `= 1`, then the query works on the SQL prompt. Now how to do it in Java is the question.

Comment: well, you need to set it as integer, i will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of

```
System.out.println(preStatement);
```

which was:

`com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement@223d2c72: SELECT * FROM mydb.SomeTable WHERE attributeId = '6' AND substring_index(substring_index(rowIdCombo,',',2),',',-1) = '1'`

and as per your comment, that replacing **= '1'** with **= 1** have solved the issue, to prevent the single quotes wrapping, set the value in the `PreparedStatement` as integer, use this:

```
preStatement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(locationID.toString()));
```

Comment: The other solution I just found is to use `"SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE attributeId = ? AND substring_index(substring_index(rowIdCombo,',',2),',',-1) = "+var+";"`. The var is `String var = num.toString();`

Comment: yes, that will work too, but if your code should be contestant, so if you are using PreparedStatement you need to keep using it :), plus it's more secure than concatenation

Comment: Using concatenation you open ways to [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).